# Unable to get a button at the bottom of a block with Tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am having an issue, I would like my "Read article" button to stay at the bottom of each column even if the "text" is bigger or shorter:

```
<--text-->
<p class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900">{!! substr($post->title, 0, 100) !!}</p>
<p class="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500">{!! substr($post->content, 0, 250) !!}</p>
<--text-->
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mx-auto mt-12 grid max-w-lg md: lg:max-w-none md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-2 lg:gap-12">
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="flex flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg h-full">
<div class="flex-shrink-0">
<img class="h-64 w-full object-fit" src="{{strlen(Storage::url($post->image1)) >= 10 ? Storage::url($post->image1) : asset('storage/images/photo-coming-soon.jpg')}}" alt="">
</div>
<div class="flex flex-col justify-between bg-white p-6">
<div class="flex-1">
<--text-->
<p class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900">{!! substr($post->title, 0, 100) !!}</p>
<p class="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500">{!! substr($post->content, 0, 250) !!}</p>
<--text-->
</div>
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse place-self-end">
<button type="button" class="mt-5 justify-self-end inline-flex items-center rounded border border-yellow bg-yellow px-2.5 py-1.5 text-xs font-medium text-black-500 shadow-md hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-yellow focus:ring-offset-2">Read Article</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

At the moment the button shows too high on some of the blocks because I have a small description compared to others.

Any idea how to get the button at the same place no matter what please?

Remember, all my blocks have the same height.

```
------------------
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|          Button|
------------------
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can add the `grow` on the parent container and give the button `mt-auto` to ensure that the parent fills the available place and the button always stick to the bottom. The same can be used to ensure that `footer` is always at the bottom

Comment: wow, thank you so much. Please add it as a reply not comment so I accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `grow` on the parent container and give the button `mt-auto` to ensure that the parent fills the available place and the button always stick to the bottom. The same can be used to ensure that `footer` is always at the bottom

Comment: Sorry for the late reply :-)  Thanks again Buddy!